# Commerce Module allowing user to customize product

Tags: commerce

is **drupal commerce** able to allow user customization of products in the following way. Imagine your product is a bike.
You want your user to:

- Change color of the bike (and therefore changing price, depending on chosen color)
- Change wheel type (and therefore price)
- Change type of break (brand for example)
- Further, the individual product should be saved (cookie for example) and one should be able to share a link to the individual product (here I saw many examples where sharing the product does not work - because you will always go to the default product)

I was looking out there but could not find many shops that solve the descriped tasks.

I used **commerce kickstart** on simplytest.me - https://ds64.ply.st/tops/guy-short-sleeve-tee
to have a quick view. If I change the color, add it to the shopping cart, click on checkout and click on edit item again, I will end up at the standard configuration. Therefore the whole configurator does not make sense if I can not edit and save my individual customized product.

**Nice to have** a descriptive text that summerizes the chosen attributes and therefor for example a max. weight of the bike could be calculated...

Nike for example generates a url with a random id that can be used to share the customized product...

http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/product/air-max-95-id/?piid=40361&pbid=166815001#?pbid=166815001

Thanks for your aswers in advance!
Pedro

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do something like this example:

https://drupalcommerce.org/videos/tutorials/customizable-products-pizza-store

Have to tweak a bit for the sharing part, probably would go with a custom module and hook_entity_view_alter() using the variables from the url to adjust for the specific changes.